# HTTP to HTTPS redirection

Tags: magento2.4.1, https, .htaccess

My site won't automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Have gone through the forums and documentations but can't figure it out so posting. I am quite newbie to Magento. I am using Magento ver. 2.4.1. What I am trying to do is this:-

[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
should automatically redirect to
https://www.mywebsite.com

My Magento settings are
[image]
[image]

My .htaccess file

```
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## enable usage of methods arguments in backtrace

    SetEnv MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 2048M
    php_value max_execution_time 36000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs.dist>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files magento_umask>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files auth.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .user.ini>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>

# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    FileETag none

# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following config to your `.htaccess` file:

```
## Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !443
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Your `.htaccess` file should looks like this:

```
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## enable usage of methods arguments in backtrace

    SetEnv MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 2048M
    php_value max_execution_time 36000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################

## redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !443
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs.dist>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files magento_umask>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files auth.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .user.ini>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>

# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    FileETag none

# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have tried it but without success. Have added those lines in the .htaccess file restarted Apache but it didn`t work. Then I tried changing "Auto-Redirect to base URL" to "No" while keeping the changes in the .htaccess file but it still didn`t work. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @DebtanuB I've added more .htaccess config. Please give it a try. What is the output of the following command? `bin/magento config:show web/secure/offloader_header`. If the value is **SSL_OFFLOADED**, try running the following command to change it to **X-Forwarded-Proto**: `bin/magento config:set web/secure/offloader_header "X-Forwarded-Proto"` and clear the cache.

Comment: I have tried adding those lines and still it is not working. Then I have changed the "offloader_header" to "X-Forwarded-Proto". But still it is not auto-redirecting. Kindly suggest. Thank you for your time & support.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.